# SQL Server Extended event Sessions?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012, powershell-3.0

I am trying script out SQL Server Extended event Sessions of SQL Server 2012 using Power-Shell but I am unable to. Can you please help me. Thanks.

below code is what I have tried.

```
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.XEvent") | Out-Null
    $cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=Sql2016;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=master");
    $cn.Open()
    $xEvents = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.XEvent.event($cn)
    $xEvents.Session | foreach {$_.Script()+";"}
    $cn.Close()
```

> Error:New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Event" and the
>   argument count: "1"

Comment: Here is the documentation for that method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.xevent.event.aspx you need to provide either no params or two params.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that but got error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. at $xEvents.Session | foreach {$_.Script()+";"}

Comment: Please edit your question and add this new information with formatting so it can be read easily.

Comment: Also, please post the entire error for both errors so we can tell exactly which line is throwing the error.